# Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side

Tags: passwords, client-side, hash

When I want to put a login system in place, I always compare the MD5 of the given password with its value in the users table on the server side.

However, a friend of mine told me that a "clear" password could be sniffed by a network software.

So my question is: is it a good idea to hash the password on the client side? Is it better than hashing it on the server side?

Comment: I was thinking of hashing the password on the client side, but only just so I can rest assured the client's password never exists as clear text on the server side, meaning they can feel easier knowing that I don't know their actual password, or can't easily give it up if compromised.  am I crazy?

Comment: Just for completeness, since we're talking about security, and MD5 was mentioned in the OP: [One should always use a salt when encrypting a password.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420843/how-does-password-salt-help-against-a-rainbow-table-attack)  Using plain, unsalted MD5 is just marginally better than storing plaintext passwords in your database.

Comment: @Cyclone Hashing ONLY at client-side is definitely a bad idea, since if the attacker somehow knows the hash, he can use it to login as if he knew the password, bypassing the client-side hashing code.

Comment: @Teejay: That's why you don't send the hash in the clear. The server sends a random salt to the client, you append the password hash, and hash the whole thing again, then send that back to the server which does the same calculation. A replay attack fails because the salt will be different

Comment: @MSalters If it is implemented as you stated, it's ok. But that's not what cyclone said.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be over at security.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @sab669: Because that would mean the client would send the unsalted hash over the network. An attacker can intercept that, and perform a replay attack. But if the client only sends salted hashes, an attacker would have to "unhash" the message to change the salt for a replay attack. And proper hash functions can't be "unhashed". (Was the comment just deleted?)

Comment: @MSalters Wouldn't SSL/TLS prevent the need for this? Even a plaintext password would still be sent securely once the connection is established? Just trying to learn, thanks

Comment: @user4779: Correct. TLS1.3 is a fairly complex protocol, but it gives you a number of guarantees. "Unreadable" is one of them, but "can't replay" is another. Still, server-side you should only store salted password hashes. This is a defense-in-depth; it limits the damage if your database leaks. TLS1.3 chiefly protects against Man-in-the-Middle (MITM).

Comment: If you implement a simple challenge response scheme (server sends challenge) then this protects against sniffing but it requires the server to have the plan password to verify it, not something you want to do. SCRAM would get around this, but IMHO is still weak. I think pre-hashing has still advantages, see below.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Basically, your friend is right. But simply hashing the password on the client side is only *just* better than submitting it as plain text to the server. Someone, who can listen for your plain text passwords is certainly also able to listen for hashed passwords, and use these captured hashes him/herself to authenticate against your server.

For this matter, more secure authentication protocols usually jump through a number of hoops in order to make sure, that such a replay attack cannot work, usually, by allowing the client to select a bunch of random bits, which are hashed along with the password, and also submitted in the clear to the server.

On the server:

- generate a few bits of random
- send these bits (in clear text) to the client

On the client:

- generate a few random bits
- concatenate password, the server's random bits and the client random bits
- generate hash of the above
- submit random bits(in clear text) and hash to the server

As the server knows its own random information as well as the client's random bits (it got them as clear text), it can perform essentially the same transformation. This protocol makes sure, that nobody listening in this conversation can use the information later to authenticate falsely using the information recorded (unless a very weak algorithm was used...), as long as both parties generate different "noise bits" each time, the hand shake is performed.

**Edit** All of this is error prone and tedious and somewhat hard to get right (read: secure). If ever possible, consider using authentication protocol implementations already written by knowledgeable people (unlike me! The above is only from memory of a book I read some time ago.) You really don't want to write this yourself usually.

Comment: How can he authenticate with the hashed password in the login system since it will be hashed again?

Comment: If you store your passwords in hashed form on the server (as you should) then the client will have to hash the password twice: first, the password alone, so it matches with the server's view of the world, and then as described above for the protocol's sake.

Comment: @Dirk, since the attacker can sniff both ways, the "random bits" would be sniffed along. Then the attacker can analyze (read: brute force) the request and response pair offline to find the original password.

Comment: @Parcerier, yes, of course. But that's not the point here. The same can be said about any kind of password hashing scheme (salting vs. rainbow tables, etc.) The random noise is added to make reply attacks hard (as in: it's hopefully too expensive to break using brute force), but cannot render them impossible.

Comment: "concatenate password, the server's random bits and the client random bits" should read "concatenate password **hash**," if your goal is to store the password in its hash form on server and combine it with this protocol

Comment: However, for the purpose of submitting a password or the hash of a password, often an asymmetric process like Diffie-Hellman is used to establish an encryption key that allows both sides to exchange information without a snooping party being able to decrypt it. This is exactly what SSL does, and is the reason that most sites have their login page on HTTPS/SSL. SSL already protects against replay attacks. I would recommend leveraging SSL rather than building your own protocol. Although I do agree with salting+hashing the password client side, but send these across an established SSL connection.

Comment: It is not that the process above is clearly flawed, but it is better to use an established public protocol that has been thoroughly reviewed and vetted, then to try and build your own and risk a mistake that will compromise your site.  Properly deployed SSL will protect against a wide variety of other attacks as well.

Comment: Just to be clear: if you're not using HTTPS, it doesn't matter what javascript you run on the client; a MITM would be able to modify the contents of your page before it hits the client. **HTTPS is the only solution.**

Comment: A question for clarification: using this schema is only possible if passwords are stored server-side *without salt*, right? When salt is used, client would need to know the salt before hashing the password with random bytes. And allowing client to obtain salt from server is a security risk? Or is it not much of a risk (provided that I somehow manage to create permanent fake salts for non-existing users)?

Comment: Note that while HTTPS is fine as a protection for real-time highjacking, it is not against an attack on logs, be they server-side debug logs, or the "transparent proxy" logs that companies are legally required to maintain in most countries. Sending passwords in clear exposes them whenever those logs will be leaked (either through negligence or after having been requested for a legal investigation)

Comment: To prevent replay attacks where the attacker re-uses a previously used hash+salt, add a nonce. For using salt+nonce in a login authentication process, see this answer: stackoverflow.com/a/24978909/43615

Comment: Reading this at a time when TLS is prevalent, this answer seems wrong and needs to be updated. Hashing client-side instead of server-side essentially turns you hash into your password. If hashes are leaked from the auth database, then the attacker can authenticate using the hash without needing to crack it first and retrieve the password.

Answer (score 81):

First of all, this does **NOT** improve the security of your application (assuming it is a web app).

**Use SSL** (Or actually TLS, which is commonly called SSL). It is free and easy to set up with [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/).

The why to this is simple. TLS solves a problem (when used with a certificate from a certificate authority, not self signed) that is quite big in cryptography: How do I know the server I am talking to is the server I think I am talking to? TLS Certificates are a way of saying: "Me, the certificate authority, trusted by your browser, certifies that the website at [url] has this public key, with a corresponding private key, which (private key) only the server knows, look I signed my signature all over the document, if anyone altered it you can see".

Without TLS, any encryption becomes pointless, because if I sit next to you in a coffeeshop, I can make your laptop/smartphone think I am the server and MiTM (Man in The Middle) you. With TLS, your laptop/smartphone will scream "UNTRUSTED CONNECTION", because I don't have a certificate authority signed certificate that matches your site. (Encryption vs. Authentication).

Disclaimer: users tend to click right through these warnings: "Untrusted connection? What? I just want my pictures of kittens! *Add Exception* *Click* *Confirm* *Click* YAY! Kittens!"

However, if you really do not want to use a certificate, still **DO implement client side Javascript hashing** (and use the Stanford library (SJCL) for that, **NEVER IMPLEMENT CRYPTO YOURSELF**).

Why? Password reuse! I can steal your session cookie (which allows me to pretend to your server that I am you) without HTTPS easily (see Firesheep). However if you add Javascript to your login page which, before sending, hashes your password (use SHA256, or even better, use SHA256, send them a public key you generated and then encrypt hashed the password with that, you cannot use a salt with this), and then sends the hashed/encrypted password to the server. **REHASH the hash on your server with a salt and compare that to what is stored in your database** (store the password like this:

```
(SHA256(SHA256(password)+salt))
```

(save the salt as plaintext in the database as well)). And send your password like this:

```
RSA_With_Public_Key(SHA256(password))
```

and check your password like this:

```
if SHA256(RSA_With_Private_Key(SHA256(sent_password))+salt_for_username) == stored_pass: login = ok
```

Because, **IF** someone is sniffing your client, they will be able to login as your client (session hijacking) but they will **NEVER** see the plaintext password (unless they alter your Javascript. However, a Starbucks hacker will probably not know how or be interested in this.) So they will gain access to your webapp, but not to their email/Facebook/etc. (for which your users will likely use the same password). (The email address will either be their login name or will be found in their profile/settings on your web app).

Comment: I thinks this is a good answer but it probably needs some more informations on how to salt properly and that it is better to use a "slow" hashing function before storing the password on server (like bcrypt).

Comment: Yes, instead of using SHA256 directly, use bcrypt or even the more secure argon2 implementation.

Comment: Applications often run behind a reverse proxy in TLS terminated servers. Sending any plaintext secrets even on HTTPS is still a no go in some corporate settings because of risks of the secrets being logged in some kind of HTTP logs after TLS terminations.

Answer (score 38):

Actually I disagree that client side hashing is more secure in this case. I think it's less secure.

The entire point of storing a hash of the password in your database as opposed to the real password (or even an encrypted password) is that it is mathematically impossible to obtain the original password from a hash (although it is theoretically possible to obtain a colliding hash input, the difficulty of which depends on the security strength of the hashing algorithm). The possible attack vector here is that if a potential attacker somehow compromised your password storage database, he/she still would not be able to obtain the original passwords of your users.

If your authentication mechanism sends a hash of the password, then in the "security breach" scenario (i.e. attacker somehow got a copy of your password database), the attacker does not need to know the real password - they just send the hashed password that they obtained from the breach and hey presto, they have access to that user's account. This completely defeats the point of storing a hashed password in the first place!

The really secure way to do it is to send the client a one-time public key for them to encrypt the password, then you decrypt and re-hash it on the server-side.

By the way, this kind of question will probably get more expert responses over on Security StackExchange.

Comment: Completely agree with this. For a client-side approach to work one would also have to send the salt to the client, which would invalidate the whole purpose of salting!

Comment: @JamesWright: The point is sending a random salt for each use, which prevents the illegal reuse of login messages. (A form of replay attacks). Sending the same salt every time is indeed pointless.

Comment: What you need to do is use a "nonce" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). That way, the server also controls the salt and makes this secure. Hashing on the client side is also important so that injected JS code can't easily find it later. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716654/43615

Comment: For using salt+nonce in a login authentication process, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978909/43615

Comment: Obviously if you hash it on the client side, you will have to hash it again on the server side to prevent the point you are making. As others point out though, for privacy you want a client side encryption already.

Comment: Sending a One time public key... isn't this what SSL does??

Comment: @user1034912 yes true, but I assumed the OP does not only want to rely on SSL for security. Some networks, especially corporate ones, have SSL terminate at some load balancer, meaning the plaintext password is visible to network components other than the serving application. Generally we use client-side encryption to avoid this and ensure e2e encryption between the client and the serving application.

Comment: Client side hashing is not pointless. You need to think about millions of user's privacy, not just one. I don't understand why people would think a hacker is able to intercept millions of people's secured connection at once to the server providing their hashed passwords. This is not just practically possible. Even if it is possible they would be smart enough to access the servers alone that hashes the user's cleartext password and can now see the hashed password and use it against the server. It makes no difference of hash or not at client side. But hashing on client side is far more safer.

Comment: In 2021, you essentially encrypt the password client-side (with TLS), and hash server-side to prevent an attacker being able to authenticate as users in case a record is leaked containing a user's login info. @STo breaking TLS isn't typically how hashes are leaked. More common is a data breach, where data at rest, not in transit, is leaked (eg., SQL injection, buffer overflow, data at exposed to the internet, rogue employee, stolen admin credentials). This doesn't mean keeping passwords client-side is pointless (eg., 1password and protonmail), it just doesn't obviate the need for server hash.

Answer (score 25):

You're likely OK not to worry about this - as Dirk mentions even if you hash the passwords a malicious user could be on a network and see the hash get sent, and could simply send the same hash themselves.

It is *slightly* better, in that it prevents the malicious user from knowing what the password is, but since they can still log in (or potentially [reconstruct the original password](https://www.freerainbowtables.com/tables/)), that's not that helpful.

In general, if you're concerned about the safety of your user's passwords and data (and you should be!), you'll want to use a secure SSL server.  If this isn't a concern for you for whatever reason you might as well not bother with hashing; it's just [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

---

**Edit Aug 2014:** Google is pushing more and more strongly for websites to [switch to HTTPS everywhere](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html), because securing the communication itself is the only way to prevent network sniffing attacks.  Attempts at obfuscating the data transmitted will only hinder, not stop, a dedicated attacker, and can give developers a dangerous false sense of security.

Comment: I think your opinion that clientside hashing is only "slightly better" is true if you are *solely* focused on getting `x` user's password and accessing a single service. If you consider the collective effect, I would say it's "much better"; because it prevents building large lookup databases of passwords used to brute force salted hashes across multiple services. IMO. See what AWS Cognito does in the client for reference.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but building on @f1lt3r 's answer, I would like to shed some light on the fact that users often use the same password for multiple services, or at least have a clear pattern. 

Personally I have chosen to hash passwords on the client side in the past just to reassure my users that my server / myself do not know what their password is

Answer (score 7):

Note that keeping passwords secure against third parties parties is not all there is to it.

As soon as privacy is involved (and when ever is it not, these days?) *you* don't want to know the password. You can't abuse or leak what you don't *have*, so both you and your clients can sleep better if you never ever see their clear-text passwords.

Therefore, hashing/encrypting client-side makes sense.

Comment: Agreed! A lot of people miss this point. If I download your password database of salted hashed passwords, and I can crack just one using a hash lookup database, then chances are I can crack them all. Once I have 50k original passwords, I now have the key to `x` users on `n` services that only encrypt on the server.  If each service uniquely hashes the password before it leaves the client, the large database of cross-service passwords gets much, much smaller. Check your AWS login traffic, see what they do. It's probability my dear Watson.

Comment: I completely agree, hashing on client side is much more logical for many reasons. If a hacker wants to know the actual hashed password, they're going to have a hard time figuring it out. It's just completely foolish and straight up dumb sending clear text passwords over "secured" connection. There is not such thing as a "secured" connection in the hacking world. Hashing the user's password on the user side can bring new security algorithms which will be extremely difficult for hackers to seem they are the actual user by tripping detection from the server.

Answer (score 6):

Recently both GitHub and Twitter announced that passwords where stored in internal logs. I've had this happen inadvertently in bug reports and other logs that found their way into splunk etc. For twitter if Trump's password was in there log it could be a big deal for an admin to "see", for other sites probably not as big of a deal as the administrators wouldn't have much use for it. Regardless as admins we don't like seeing the passwords do we.

So the question is really if the hashing should happen client side for security, but how can we protect the password before it ultimately gets hashed and compared by the server side so it doesn't get logged somehow.

Encryption is not a bad idea because the developers at least have to jump through some hoops, and if you find that passwords got into logs you can just change the encryption key, destroy the original, and that data becomes useless. Better yet rotate the keys nightly and it could reduce the windows greatly.

You could also hash a hash in your user record. The leaked passwords would be hashed plain text passwords. The server would store a hashed version of the hash. Sure the hash becomes the password, but unless you've got a photographic memory you are not going to remember a 60 char bcyrpt. Salt with the username. If you could gather something about the user during the login process (while not exposing that the user record exists ) you can salt with that as well creating a more robust hash that couldn't be shared between sites. No man in the middle would be able to just cut and paste the captured hash between sites.

Combine with a cookie that doesn't get submitted back to the server and you might be onto something. On first request submit a cookie to the client with a key, then make sure that cookie doesn't make its way back to the login service so little chance of it being logged. Store the key in a session store, and then delete it right after login occurs or when session expired... this requires state for you JWT guys, but maybe just use a nosql service for it.

So down the road an admin comes across one of these hashed and encrypted passwords in splunk or a bug reporting tool. It should be useless to them as they can't find the encryption key anymore, and even if they did they then have to brute force a hash. In addition the end user didn't send anything plaintext along the line so any man in the middle at least has a harder time of it and you can't just hop to another site and login.

Comment: Exactly my concern. If the server somehow logs by accident due to poor implementation or malicious intent, then it's possible that other account of the user can be compromised if they reuse passwords.

Comment: If you were authenticating with a hash generated from the password client-side, you wouldn't want to see that in the logs either.

Answer (score 3):

It depends, you can use client side hashing, but server side salt will not be possible.

have a look at the link
[Password encryption at client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121629/password-encryption-at-client-side)

Answer (score 2):

This idea of client side hashing is to protect the user, not your site. As mentioned many times already, plain text or hashed passwords both have access to your site equally. You don't get a security benefit.

But your users actual, plain text, password should only be known by them. Knowing what they chose as a password is information that can be used against them on other sites and systems. You are being a customer-focused site by protecting them from having their password choice discovered by your server devs or by third parties.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing a lot of work on this recently, IRL there are two issues with client side hash / *symmetric* encryption with really kill the idea:
1. You have to get the salt back to the server SOMEHOW...and to encrypt it client side you'd need a password...which defeats the purpose.
2. You expose your hashing implementation (not a HUGE deal as most sites use one of 3 or 4 hashing algos) which makes the attack easier (as just need to try one rather than n).

What I eventually went to was asymmetric encryption on the client using OpenPGP.js or similar...
This relies on an imported or client side generated key on the client and the server sending it's public key. Only the client's public key may be sent back to the server. 
This protects against MIM attacks and is as secure as the device (I currently store client's private key by default in localStore, it's a demo).

The MAJOR advantage of this is that I never have to have users data stored / even in memory unencrypted on my server / data store (and my server's private key is physically separate)

The basis of this was to provide people a way to communicate securely where HTTPS was restricted (e.g., Iran / N. Korea atc...) and also just a fun experiment.

I'm FAR from the first to think of this, http://www.mailvelope.com/ uses this

Answer (score 1):

If someone can see the data in and out on your connection then authentication will not save you.
Instead I would do the following for super secret stuff.

Passwords prehashed on client side before sent to server.
(Server stores another hashed and salted value of that hash sent from the browser).

So a middle man attack could allow them to send the same hashed value to login as them, but the users password would not be known. This would stop them trying other services with the same credentials to login elsewhere.

Users data is encrypted on the browser side too.

Ah, so a middle man attack would get the encrypted data, but would not be able to decrypt it without the actual password used to login. (users password stored in the DOM on the browser when they logged in).
So the real user would see the decrypted contents but the middle man could not.
This also means any NSA or other agency would not be able to request you/company/hosting provider to decrypt this data as it would be impossible for them to do so as well.

Some small examples of both of these methods are on my blog
http://glynrob.com/javascript/client-side-hashing-and-encryption/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:-

Client sends request to server "I have a password to validate".

Server sends client a one-time only random string. R$

Client embeds the user's password in this string (based on any (variable) rules you wish to apply).

Client sends the string to the server and if password OK, server logs user in.

Should server receive another login request using R$, user is logged out and the account is frozen pending investigation.

Obviously all other (normal) security precautions would be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The method that I have come up with is to use SHA-256 with multiple rounds and a random salt...

```
salt = generate random salt
hash = sha256(password)
for (i = 0 to rounds)
    hash = sha256(hash + salt)
```

This encrypts the password in such a way that only the user knows what the password is.  Both salt and hash are stored in the database.  I have also implemented this on the client side using a server generated random string.

```
server_data = {
    algorithm,
    rounds,
    salt,
    string
}

hash = hash(server_data.algorithm, password)
for (i = 0 to server_data.rounds)
    hash = hash(server_data.algorithm, hash + salt)
hash = hash(server_data.algorithm, hash + server_data.string)
```

In crypto class, we were taught that the attacker can know the algorithm, salt, rounds, etc....  But in this case, the actual hashed password is never sent.  The server knows what the random string that it sent was, so the full hash is generated on the client, and the final piece is to hash that result with the random string.  That's the result that's sent to the server.  The result is effectively a one-time password that is useless on replay attacks.  The user's password is never sent in the clear, and if the attacker gained the password hash, it would be useless to them because the server will not accept it in that form.  The hacker **MAY** be able to compute a rainbow table for the salt and the number of rounds to try and brute force the password, but any sufficintly complex password using ASCII symbols 32-126 of at least 8 characters long will usually take a long time to crack...and that's for **EACH** password.  The sites that I write for can have passwords up to 128 characters in length.

As for session hijacking, that risk can be reasonably mitigated by regenerating the session ID every 30 seconds or so.  I also include a token that's embedded in the HTML of the page itself.  On the server side, some of the client information such as the client's IP address and user agent string are hashed as well and stored in the user's session data.

So on each request, the server gets the cookie session ID and the token.  The token is compared to what is in the session data.  The other information such as the IP address and user agent are hashed and compared to what's in the session as well.  If it all matches, then there's a very high probability that this is the real user and not an intruder.

The only way that I can see this happening is if the attacker has the embedded token, the same IP address, and the same user agent.  It's all about probabilities.  Besides, any time you are dealing with crypto, it can be hard to get right.  So as others have said, don't do it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

It's 2022 now. As hacker attacks are getting more sophisticated, luckily also have browser standards. The defacto transmission protocol is encrypted (https) and cross site scripting or replay attacks systematically are more difficult with [content security policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

I believe your time will be well spend familiarising yourself with these technologies.

I'm not a security expert and leave that in the hands of more capable engineers.