# Password encryption using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to encrypt my password using base 64. How can i do it in javascript?

Comment: Sivajith, Base-64 is an *encoding*, not *encryption*, scheme. It does not protect your passwords in any way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121629/password-encryption-at-client-side  if you are looking for encryption and not encoding

Answer (score 1):

base64 is a method to encode data and not an encryption technique. If that is still the approach you want to take then here is a JavaScript library that will work: https://github.com/mshang/base64-js

There is also a built in method in Mozilla and web kit browsers called btoa():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa