# How to apply password encryption with Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, jcryption

I recently started working on adding security in an existing web application. The application uses [jcryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) to encrypt the hashed password before sending it to server and then at server side we do the decryption to get the hashed value and than this hashed value is compared with the db password field(MD5 hashed value). That way we can handle "Man in the middle attacks". The setup worked fine till I introduced Spring Security layer in the application (Spring Security 3.2.7 with Java configuration) now I have problem in encryption part and I really have no idea how to proceed.

Everything else is working and I have used Md5PasswordEncoder for hashing the passwords. The problem is username and passwords are being sent in plain text. I can't understand how can I encrypt the password before sending it over the network. **How can I apply AES encryption/decryption of username/ password field along with Spring security architecture ?**

Please understand I am already using **MD5** hashing in my application and I want an encryption layer above it. One more thing since it is a legacy application **I can't force everyone to use HTTPS, https is enabled but that is not mandatory for all. I am more concerned about people who will be accessing the application using plain old http.**

Comment: You aren't handling the the man-in-the-middle attack. 2 way encryption is only a layer of indirection. Also when you have a man-in-the-middle he still gets the hashed password, with which he can still login. So basically you are adding complexity without gaining anything... IMHO.

Comment: @M.Deinum Doesn't jcryption provide two way authentication as well ? Isn't unique key and challenge is used before sending the values to server ?  I am still learning jcryption so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't know jcryption, but generally when doing two way encryption it only adds complexity. Your connection should already be secured (https). A man-in-the-middle attack is generally about retrieving cookies and then use that session cookie to steal the session. But there is a java version [here](https://jcryptionforjava.wordpress.com) albeit an old one. You can probably fit it into Spring Security or a plain filter.

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to use HTTPS to send your users' passwords over the internet.

   Seriously, your users can/will sue you if you don't do this. LinkedIn recently gave up a few million dollars for not taking due care with their users' passwords.

   LetsEncrypt is free and widely used.
2. Doing encryption without HTTPS or hashing on the client is wrong and bad. Hash on the server only.
3. MD5 is the worst possible hashing method. Again, you might get sued.

   Only use the following: bcrypt, scrypt, PBKDF-2

   Spring has a built-in [bcrypt password encoder](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I am already using https in my application but it is not mandatory and about 20-25% users use the application from other means which are not https supported i.e. Desktop client etc. How can I apply password encryption for them ?

Comment: @amit how/why do they not support https?

Comment: Desktop client code is legacy code and I don't have authority to change it and management seems not interested in changing the code either.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own PasswordEncoder with spring security but first you need to AES encrypt / decryption code , here is example :

```
 public static String encrypt(String value) {

    if(value == null){
        return value;
    }
    // SALT is your secret key
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(SALT.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}

   public static String decrypt(String value) {

    if(value == null){
        return value;
    }
    // SALT is your secret key
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(SALT.getBytes(), "AES");
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(value)));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Then we can use these utility methods with PasswordEncoder by the way you don't need to decrypt user password while authentication,it's not safe, you must encode password and then compare  encoded passwords. (you must save user passwords encoded in database)
Here is example:

public class CustomUserPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

```
public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
    return encrypt(rawPassword.toString());
}

public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(rawPassword) && encode(rawPassword).equals(encodedPassword)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Now, we can set  spring security password encoder like this:

```
 passwordEncoder(new CustomUserPasswordEncoder());
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for your answer, BTW I have no plans decrypting the passwords and bringing it to plain text, I will only encrypt the hashed value.. and on the server side only the hashes will be compared. One more thing how can I encrypt the values before submitting form at client side.

Comment: You can get information from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121629/password-encryption-at-client-side