# I want to encrypt password at client side and decrypt password using asymmetric keys

Tags: java, javascript, encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

I have to encrypt password form client side and decrypt it on server side. Then this decrypted password is passed through ldap. I get true or false in return as response. I cannot use MD5 as password cannot be retrieved form that. Is there any algorithm or api that can be used to encrypt and decrypt the same.

Comment: Use SSL. Then everything is encrypted.

Comment: I am using ssl. We have a guideline that with ssl I have to do encrypt the password also.

Comment: Then challenge the guideline. Client-side encryptions is pretty pointless anyway. What's the point of encrypting something that's already encrypted?

Comment: I will try to challenge the guideline. Hope it will work. But in the mean time want to find a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest password encryption on client side (and really, really don't suggest writing own).
Using SSL for login, then handling password things in your back-end is the way to go.

If no other choice and need JS encryption, here are some SO discussions which might help:

- [Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715920/about-password-hashing-system-on-client-side)
- [Password encryption at client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121629/password-encryption-at-client-side)