# How to encrypt password by client side jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, encryption

Help me with decision.
I have jsp page with password field:

```
<div>
   <label for="p">Password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="pass" id="p" />
</div>
```

I need (on client side) to encrypt to MD5, for example, and send to servlet. I don't want to use jsp scriptlets, because it is not best decision in JAVA. Maybe somebody know how to write js function?

Comment: What's the point in encrypting the password on the client side?

Comment: and, MD5 is no encryption, it's a hashing algorithm

Comment: MD5 is hashing not encrypting (and is a poor choice for the former anyway) If you want to securely pass data from the client to the server use HTTPS, thats what its for.

Comment: Did you search MD5 JavaScript.... but not sure what the point is

Comment: Recent browsers have a crypto API that you might like: http://caniuse.com/#feat=cryptography, yet, what's the point of it?

Comment: Client-side encryption using JS is mostly pointless: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password encryption at client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121629/password-encryption-at-client-side)

Comment: Do not encrypt the password on the client side, send the password to the server over HTTPS. On the server side iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: You've tagged this question with the ssl tag, and SSL is the answer. Curious.

Comment: @snip1377 there is no ssl tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that can encrypt your input on client side and transfer it to the server in encrypted form.

You can use following **libs**:

- [jcryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) . Client-Server asymmetric encryption over Javascript

Update after 3 years:

- [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/)

Update after 4 years (Wohoo!)

- [CryptoJS - Easy to use encryption](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)
- [ForgeJS - Pretty much covers it all](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)

you can use this too:

- [OpenPGP.JS - Put the OpenPGP format everywhere](http://openpgpjs.org/)

runs in JS so you can use it in your web apps, mobile apps & etc.

Comment: "You *can* use following libs:" ... I guess you *can* but certainly don't view them as a substitute for using https.

Comment: He/she can use them.he/she can choose one of them and read about it

Comment: He/she can use them.he/she can choose one of them and read about it