# Rails + Backbone.js - Hide secured data in page source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, backbone.js

I'm using API to fetch data from the backbone with some secured headers.

```
index: function() {  
  this.collection.fetch({ beforeSend: setHeader });
}

var setHeader = function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'XXXX');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('AppKey', 'YYYYY');
}
```

When i do a page source i'm able to see the 'Authorization' and 'AppKey'. Is there any way to hide it, as its a secured data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to hide it in the page source from the person visiting your website. This is because of the way the internet works, all the website contents are downloaded to the visitors browser and it would be very nasty if developers could hide things from the visitor.

So, you really don't have any way of hiding those from a page visitor that knows his stuff, if the they are in plain text in the sources. And even if they were somehow hidden, when that request is launched, the user could just check the network tab of his developer tools and get the info from there.

If you want to prevent some kind of man-in-the-middle attack (eg. some third person catching those headers), use SSL (so your site goes through https) and maybe do some client side encryption so they don't move through the wire unencrypted.

For a place to start with the client side encryption:

[Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715920/about-password-hashing-system-on-client-side)