# Why almost all webservers dont hash your password on client side?

Tags: hash, md5

Is it more secured to encode text to md5 for example on client side then send via post method and store on server database as md5 hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715920/is-it-worth-hashing-passwords-on-the-client-side)

Comment: generally passwords should be sent over tls which is more secure and doesn't make public your hashing scheme

Comment: If I can sniff your password and impersonate you, then I can also sniff the hash and impersonate you. There is exactly zero difference between the two. Also note that MD5 is absolutely terrible as a password hashing function. MD5 is fast, password hashing functions should be slow.

Comment: MD5 is not a secure password hashing algorithm. Please avoid implementing password hashing, it's much harder than it sounds because you won't get an error if you do it wrong. Your system will work just fine while being really insecure.