# How to store password info in database, using ReactJS frontend?

Tags: mysql, database, reactjs, authentication, passwords

I'm just looking for general guidance on this topic, as I am fairly new to all of this.

So, I have a react app, which generates login information for a given list of emails. What it does is that it creates an array that contains the given emails and automatically generates a password for each email, so then people can log in with their premade accounts. These accounts are meant for a one time use only, so once they submit what they need to fill out, they won't be able to modify their submission.

Now, I am generating the passwords in the frontend and then sending them directly to the database, but I would like to know where in this process are passwords supposed to be hashed? Is it a frontend thing or a backend thing? Is there a problem with sending the array with the passwords directly to the database as is? Also, currently, everything runs over HTTP, how can I force an HTTPS connection for the pages, so passwords are safer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, currently, everything runs over HTTP, how can I force an HTTPS connection for the pages, so passwords are safer?
You need to get SSL certificate. There is a link will help you https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/free-https-c051ca570324
About hashing... Already asked. There was completed answer [Is it worth hashing passwords on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715920/is-it-worth-hashing-passwords-on-the-client-side)