# Angular build fails after adding argon2 or bcrypt from npm

Tags: angular, build, node-modules, monorepo, argon2-ffi

I have an Angular project where I want to use argon2 library to encrypt passwords.
I added it to the back end, the implementation it's fine but my Angular front end app started to break.

I get a huge list of errors like:

```
ERROR in /<project>/node_modules/argon2/node_modules/minizlib/constants.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/<project>/node_modules/argon2/node_modules/minizlib'
```

This is just one of the errors, I have similar errors for modules like `crypto, fs, http, https, os, path, stream` and many others. Same happens if I use `bcrypt`.

Do you know what is issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn’t support working with node js modules
Like fs and more.
U could find a package for encrypting password  from npm to do the work instead.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is my project is an NX mono repo and I was importing something from a backend lib that brought in the angular code also the crypto lib and then my build was failing. I solved duplicating some code. But for whom has the same problem I can suggest `crypto-js` to hash passwords in the frontend (but I've been told that's not a good practice).

Comment: @chenny [Another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716654/8740349) proves hashing-passwords to be **best but maybe too hard** practice.