# Angular make secure login/register page

Tags: angular, security, hash

I would like to create a registration and login page in my angular 12 project. Therefore I need to salt & pepper and then hash my password. I looked for some examples but all were for javascript but I need it for typescript.

When the password is secure, Angular should send it with an http request to the backend (Spring Boot).

Have someone an idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You **don't need** to hash passwords on the client side. Most of the useful protection you gain from doing this is provided by communicating in HTTPS with your backend (assuming the CA you use is trusted and your network not compromised). This is because someone who can read your packets pre-encryption most likely have access to your machine and can simply key-log your password which renders the hashing useless. You **do need** to hash your passwords before saving them in your database so a data leak doesn't give raw passwords.

Comment: So I just need to hash it on the backend?

Comment: Yep, this is a common misconception when making a secure application. In most cases, if someone by-passed HTTPS, you can assume there is nothing you can do client side to make things secure except kick the intruder off of your network/machine.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You shouldn't rely on HTTPS alone, even though it's secure enough. AFAIK the primary goal of hashing is not to expose the user's password to the server (and to the attacker). It also slows down the client from dictionary based brute-forcing. As the password derivation function is costly you have to do it on the client. A good answer to this topic is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391242/should-i-hash-the-password-before-sending-it-to-the-server-side

Comment: You don't have to do it on the client. One of the only reason i can see for having hashing client side is true zero knowledge security. Meaning the password is never in clear on the server, even in transit. Its often used in very high security systems. It is however not necessary for most systems as this attack is mainly carried out as an inside job or the client's machine is comprised. If the client machine's is compromised, a key logger will defeat it anyways and an inside job is better protected against with rigorous processes.

Comment: I somewhat agree with the benchmark part but i'd rather benchmark my own machines (servers) and tune the hashing algorithms to that because every single client's computer might be different. I find the reward vs work not worth it for a majority of applications.

Comment: My previous comment was not complete and only highlighted the pros of client-side hashing. Now I agree that server-side hashing is more important and in some scenarios it is enough. If the database were to be leaked, an attacker cannot simply use the hash to impersonate any user, because the server never skips the hashing (unlike client-side hashing). This means you need the original password to log in, which is expensive even with a leaked database. However, the ideal process would use both client and server side hashing. (but unfortunately I can't undo my downvote until the answer is edited)