# How to encrypt password from login input in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, passwords, laravel-blade

I am working on a small Laravel application, the problem is with the login, it works fine, but I just found out that the password can be seen if you have the basic knowledge to inspect the request payload. I want to know how can I encrypt the password or what solution can there be for this.

Blade file:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('Login') }}">
   @csrf

   <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }} mb-3">
      <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
         <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
         </div>
         <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Correo') }}" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" value="admin@argon.com" required autofocus>
      </div>
      @if ($errors->has('email'))
         <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
         </span>
      @endif
      </div>
      <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
         <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-lock-circle-open"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" placeholder="{{ __('Contraseña') }}" type="password" required>
         </div>
           @if ($errors->has('password'))
              <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
              </span>
           @endif
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-4">{{ __('Iniciar sesión') }}  </button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Login controller:

```
public function Login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $this->validate(request(),[
        'email'=>'email|required|string',
        'password'=>'required|string'
    ]);

    try
    {
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            $roleStdClass = DB::table('users')->where('email', $credentials['email'])->select('role_idrole')->first();

            $role = current((array) $roleStdClass);

            session(['rol'=> $role]);

            $id = DB::table('users')->where('email', $credentials['email'])->select('id')->first();
            $imgRoute = DB::table('users')->where('email', $credentials['email'])->select('photo')->first(); 
            $idConvert = current((array) $id);
            $userPhoto = current((array) $imgRoute);
            session(['id'=> $idConvert]);
            session(['userEmail' => $credentials['email']]);
            session(['userPhoto' => $userPhoto]);

            if($role == 3)
            {
                return redirect()->route('main');
            }

            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        else
        {
            return back()->withErrors(['email' => trans('auth.failed')]);
        }   

    }catch(Exception $ex)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(['email' => trans('auth.failed')]);
    }
}
```

I really don't know how to solve this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the password can be seen from the page, because only the user who typed it has access to it (unless your site is vulnerable to XSS attacks, but you'd take different steps to mitigate that). Just ensure you use HTTPS on your site and then no-one can intercept the details between the browser and the server. (Also, even if you encrypted the password on the client side, it wouldn't really be useful because the user of the browser could also see the code used for the encryption and would therefore be able to learn how to decrypt it.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I hash the password before sending it to the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391242/should-i-hash-the-password-before-sending-it-to-the-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
'password' => Hash::make($request->yourpassword)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I had already tried this, but the password is still seen from the browser when inspecting the page.

Comment: Please explain why the OP should try your way? and what is the issue in their approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check user once. With password you can check like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

$userValidated = DB::table('users')->where(['email' => $credentials['email'],'password'=> Hash::make($credentials['password'])])->first();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how this could help with the problem, as I explained in the question the password can be seen from the browser when someone inspects the page, what I want to know is how can I encrypt the password sent from the form. As I see, this will hash the password after the data reaches the controller.

Comment: Okay, but if you want to hide password in front, it is not possible. Because you need to check password for if(Auth::attempt($credentials)). For encryption, you must use https  (SSL) protocol for to hide connection credentials from others. Otherwise, any case your encryption will broken.