# html form field transformation

Tags: javascript, html

Given a form in HTML5

```html
<form action="/login/password" method="post">
  <section>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="password" required>
  </section>
  <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

When clicking the submit button, how can the `password` field be transformed. For example, rather than send the `password` field as is, submit `hash(password)` instead (where `hash()` function is given)

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21716654/2813224).

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks for the reference. That's exactly what I am trying to achieve. That is, sending the hash value of the password and not the password itself. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Mr. what's the point? If the attacker gets that hash and send it to the server it won't help.

Comment: @AlPo In case the server will be hacked and the database will be leaked, still there won't be any passwords in it.

Comment: @Mr. No offense, but please read a password management 101 article somewhere. Keywords: Password hash and salt

Comment: @Mr. you can do `hash()` on a server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `onsubmit` event, you can do anything with the `<input>` fields values:

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
  this.password.value = hash(this.password.value);
  console.log( [... new FormData(this)] );
  return false; // prevent sent form for example
}

function hash(value) {
  return btoa(value);
}
```

```html
<form action="/login/password" method="post">
  <section>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" required autofocus>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" autocomplete="password" required>
  </section>
  <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

---

P.S. Password hashing should be done on the server side, not on the front end.